# Rust trait with multiple members, implemented by default, that depend on each other

Tags: rust, traits

Suppose I want to introduce a trait with 2 methods, that are dependent on each other in the sense, that one of them can be implemented by default using another. For example:

```
use std::io;

trait SpecificSerializationStrategy: Sized {
  fn deserialize_slice(bytes: &[u8]) -> Self {
    // IO operations on inmemory buffers are infallible
    Self::deserialize_stream(bytes).unwrap()
  }

  fn deserialize_stream(mut stream: impl io::Read) -> io::Result<Self> {
    let mut bytes = vec![];
    stream.read_to_end(&mut bytes)?;    

    Ok(Self::deserialize_bytes(&bytes))
  }
}
```

This case is not only limited to serializing and quite often can be encountered in some crates (unfortunatly, I cannot remember exact examples of such, but I will update this question as soon as I encounter them).

Obviously, if at least on of the functions is not implemented, this default implementation causes infinite recursion. But when I used this pattern previously, Rust compiler was able to recognize the case and require from implementing types AT LEAST ONE of co-dependent members.

I am not sure, as of what changed, but now, this case of default implementations passes.

Is it compiler change? Or am I missing some specific attribute for trait definition/just doing this pattern incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has never worked.

The language designers are interested in this use-case (at least initially for [`std::io::Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html), that also has this pattern with `read()` and `read_buf()`), and it's available on nightly as `#[rustc_must_implement_one_of(deserialize_slice, deserialize_stream)]` on the trait, but this attribute is internal and not exposed currently.